# SQL Server Performance of Query with and without using CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have two different queries that return 10 records per page. But in my second query I have updated it in a way to return total records count as well, and it has been achieved using the CTE. Now I am reluctant to use it and wanted to know the performance impacts as now it is using CTE in `Query 02`. Will CTE pick all the records of table in memory and make it memory intensive? How much can be the performance difference between both these queries? Because if there's a huge performance difference then I can skip the total count. Please suggest.

```
DECLARE
@PageSize tinyint=10,
@PageOffset int=0;

--Query 01
SELECT
    App.Id,
    Users.FirstName+' '+Users.LastName as Name,
    App.Date
FROM
    App
    INNER JOIN Users ON App.UserId = Users.Id
WHERE
    App.FolderId = 1
ORDER BY
    App.Date DESC
OFFSET @PageOffset ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;

--Query 02
WITH TempResult AS(
    SELECT
        App.Id,
        Users.FirstName+' '+Users.LastName as Name,
        App.Date
    FROM
        App
        INNER JOIN Users ON App.UserId = Users.Id
    WHERE
        App.FolderId = 1
), TempCount AS (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS MaxRows FROM TempResult
)
SELECT *
FROM TempResult, TempCount
ORDER BY
    TempResult.Date DESC
OFFSET @PageOffset ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: what did your tests reveal ?

Comment: I didn't compare them

Comment: Don't think the CTE would change the query plan much, but to propose an alternative: you could use `Count` with a window function in your first query as well (assuming you have sql server 2008 or newer). e.g. adding the field `count(1) over () cnt` to the first query will add a field named cnt with the count of all records returned by the query

Comment: Yes you are right but I think CTE will be good choice because using CTE I can select count only once in a separate record set instead of repeating with every row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you are using multiple subqueries for this.  The best way to write the query uses window functions:

```
SELECT a.Id, (u.FirstName + ' '+ u.LastName) as Name, a.Date,
       COUNT(*) OVER () as MaxRows 
FROM App a INNER JOIN
     Users u
     ON a.UserId = u.Id
WHERE a.FolderId = 1;
```

As for performance, this depends on whether you are measuring the time to the *first* row or the *last* row.  Your initial query can start returning results as they are generated, because there is no `ORDER BY` or `GROUP BY` or window functions.  This has nothing to do with the presence of a CTE.

Any version that has the total count needs to generate the entire result set.  That requires generating all the results internally, before returning anything.

You should test to see if the query meets your performance needs.

Comment: Is it efficient to use window function ?

Comment: @alsha . . . A window function should be the most efficient approach.

Answer (score 0):

CTE-s as well as views are optimization boundaries. I.e. the query plans won't be able to optimize the `WITH` queries together with the outer query. In your case it's not much an issue because the outer query is simple. It's a [Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of two tables.

A Cartesian Product is usually discouraged. However, one of the *views* contains only one line. so it should be fine.

Comment: So the difference between both the queries is not much. Right? Because for me count is not as much important as performance. :)

Comment: Actually the concern is that first query only selects 10 records. But in second query there's paging limit in outer query not in the CTE. So, I am curious that will it make bigger impacts to select all records in memory?

Comment: Awm the `OFFSET` clause... In this case it **has** an impact. The CTE version will  firstretrieve more rows than necessary, and then it'll filter the not required rows.

Comment: First thing first: do you need to calculate the `TempCount .MaxRows` based on the window or based on the full `TempResult ` query? Each approach needs a different query. You might check Table variables or temporary tables too.

Comment: Either from window or from TempResult query, but the one more resource efficient

Comment: CTE it is then. However, I don't know how to add the paging to the `TempResult` query. On the other hand, this will makes `MaxRows` equal to  `@PageSize`, except the last page maybe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145406/discussion-between-alsha-and-tamas-rev).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are to do paging and find total record both,I use window function.

It give help my in both with single row-number function.

Please correct rest part of the query .Like Calculate @From and @To .correct row_number () part suiting your need.Also notice the commneted part and use whichever is faster.

```
DECLARE @PageSize tinyint=10,
@PageOffset int=0;

--Query 01
;with CTE as
(
SELECT
    App.Id,
    Users.FirstName+' '+Users.LastName as Name,
    App.Date ,ROW_NUMBER()over(order by date desc) rn
FROM
    App
    INNER JOIN Users ON App.UserId = Users.Id
WHERE
    App.FolderId = 1

)
select * 
,(select max(rn) from cte) TotalRecords
--,(select top 1 rn from cte order by rn desc) TotalRecords
from cte
where rn between @From and @To
```